# Let A = $\left\{1,\:2,\:\left\{1,\:2\right\}\right\}$, how many elements are in the set $P(A)\setminus A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

My thinking:

A = $\left\{1,\:2,\:\left\{1,\:2\right\}\right\} $ (which contains three elements)

The power set of $A$, $P(A)$ then contains $2^3 = 8$ elements which are:

$P(A) = \left\{\right\},\:\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{\left\{1,2\right\}\right\},\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{1,\left\{1,2\right\}\right\},\:\left\{2,\:\left\{1,2\right\}\right\},\:\left\{1,2,\left\{1,2\right\}\right\}$

Therefore, $P(A)\setminus A$ = $\left\{\right\},\:\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{\left\{1,2\right\}\right\},\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{1,\left\{1,2\right\}\right\},\:\left\{2,\:\left\{1,2\right\}\right\}$ which has **7 elements.**

I'm not too sure if this is right, but if anyone could help me out, that would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $/$? Set difference?

Comment: @Hermis14 yes, "\" was giving me problems in Latex

Comment: You are missing $\{$ at the beginning of your power sets.

Comment: But $1,2\notin P(A),$ since they are not sets (unless you define $1,2$ as sets, but then, at least under the usual approach, $1=\{\{\}\},$ and $2=\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\},$ and then $\{\}\in1,2$ and $\{\}\notin A.$)

Comment: There are 7 elements, but not for the reason you have. It is because $\{1,2\}$ is an element of both and hence not in the difference. $\{1,2\{1,2\}\}$ is equal to $A$ but is not an element of $A$

Comment: MathJax tip: you don't need all the `\left` and `\right` commands. MathJax will work perfectly fine if you just write, for example, `\{\{1, 2\}\}` = $\{\{1, 2\}\}$. The purpose of these commands is for when you want your grouping symbols to grow to meet the size of what's contained in them. You delineate what, from your expression, you want the grouping symbols to fit, using the `\left` and `\right` commands. Compare, for example, `$(\frac{1}{1-x^2})^2$` =  $(\frac{1}{1-x^2})^2$ with `$\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)^2$` =  $\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the right number of elements, but the wrong elements listed for $P(A)\setminus A$.

You correctly noted that the power set of $A$ is

$$P(A)=\left\{\quad \{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{\{1,2\}\},\{1,2\},\{1,\{1,2\}\},\{2,\{1,2\}\},\{1,2,\{1,2\}\}\quad\right\}$$

However, note that $\{1,2,\{1,2\}\}=A\not\in A$, so this element is not removed from the power set by taking the set difference of $A$.

Instead, note that $\{1,2\}\in A$ and also $\{1,2\}\in P(A)$. Thus this element is removed by taking the set difference.

As a result:

$$P(A)\setminus A=\left\{\quad \{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{\{1,2\}\},\{1,\{1,2\}\},\{2,\{1,2\}\},\{1,2,\{1,2\}\}\quad\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$A$ has $3$ elements, so $P(A)$ has $2^3=8$ elements.

If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, $X\setminus Y=X\setminus(Y\cap X)$,
so $P(A)\setminus A$ is the same as $P(A)\setminus(A\cap P(A))$.

So how many elements does $A\cap P(A)$ have?

$A$ has $3$ elements, namely, $1$, $2$, $\{1,2\}$;
$1$ is not a subset of $A$, $2$ is not a subset of $A$, $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of $A$;
so $1\notin P(A)$, $2\notin P(A)$, $\{1,2\}\in P(A)$;
so $A\cap P(A)$ has just one element, namely $\{1,2\}$;
so $P(A)\setminus A$ has $8-1=7$ elements.